# Automatically include libraries in the WAR folder

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, google-plugin-eclipse

I use Eclipse and I installed Google plug-in. I created an empty google -> web application project. I want to upload the project to gitHub but only the source code without the libraries that are included in war folder. I want to know if there is an automatic process to include the libs when cloning the project.

Comment: I don't use maven or android studio module for that. I use similar project like [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-java)

Comment: i understand that you're not using maven, but asking what to use. I suggest to try maven or gradle. that was your question, right?